# Java Get All Files in a Package

Tags: java

I'm trying to get all the files in a package in Java using this code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getThemes() {
        ArrayList<String> themes = new ArrayList<>();

    File folder = new File(Main.class.getResource("fxml/").toString());

        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".css"))
                themes.add(file.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", ""));
        }

    return themes;
}
```

This code is supposed to give me an ArrayList of all the css files in the package called `fxml` (Full: `dev.thetechnokid.rw.fxml`).

I've used many other different ways, including using the current directory and the complete file path, but it still gives a `NullPointerException`. The stack trace doesn't give enough info, just the FXML `LoadException`.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: which package of Main.class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>I'm pretty sure Class.getResource() only detects files, not folders.</s> <-- I stand corrected.

Class.getResource is not a very useful abstraction here.
This mechanism is mainly useful when you don't know whether a resource will be in a file system or inside an archive. The ClassLoader abstracts that away.

In your case you know you have files, so you might as well use their API directly:

```
List<String> cssFileNames = Files.walk(Paths.get("fxml"))
                                 .map(Path::getFileName)
                                 .map(Path::toString)
                                 .filter(n -> n.endsWith(".css"))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if you really must use the ClassLoader, one trick is to start with a known file, then move up one level and go from there:

```
Path path = new File(
        Main.class.getResource("fxml/iKnowThisFileExists.txt").toURI()
).getParentFile().toPath();
List<String> cssFileNames2 = Files.walk(path)
                                 .map(Path::getFileName)
                                 .map(Path::toString)
                                 .filter(n -> n.endsWith(".css"))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Class.getResource()` can detect folder, `Path.get("fxml")` i don't think it work because it depend on DefaultFileSystem

Comment: @Jerry06 you're right about the first part, but I fail to see what's wrong with relying on the default file system

Comment: Thank you! The first one gave me an error for some reason but the second one worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try use `getFile` instead of `toString`

`File folder = new File(Main.class.getResource("fxml/").getFile());`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
URL packageURL;
packageURL = classLoader.getResource("fxml/"); 
URI uri = new URI(packageURL.toString());
File folder = new File(uri.getPath());
```